# Multiple functions at the same time with Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, programming

I would like to make a stepper motor run in for loop in time intervals. I also want to stepper motor run when I press the button. Two functions independently. One does not affect the other. I wrote both functions but I have no idea how to make them both work in the same time. I'm using an Arduino Uno.

This is my code:

```
const int stepPin = 3; 
const int dirPin = 4;
const int buttonPin = 2; 

void setup() {
  pinMode(stepPin,OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(dirPin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}
void loop() {

 // One function
   digitalWrite(dirPin,HIGH);

  for(int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
    digitalWrite(stepPin,HIGH); 
    delayMicroseconds(3000); 
    digitalWrite(stepPin,LOW); 
    delayMicroseconds(3000); 
    }
  delay(30000);
    }
 

// Second function
  digitalWrite(dirPin,HIGH);
buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
if (buttonState == HIGH) {
  digitalWrite(stepPin,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(3000); 
  digitalWrite(stepPin,LOW); 
  delayMicroseconds(3000);
}
```

Can anyone help me? :)

Comment: You can’t do this with blocking code.  You’ll have to rewrite loop so that it can repeat over and over very fast and doesn’t have to stop and wait for anything to happen.  It’s called non-blocking code and it’s probably your first lesson in real coding.  Instead of thinking of a for loop that takes the action from start to finish, think of a loop function that takes one tiny step and then comes back around next time to take the next step.   Look up the blink without delay example and any of the myriad tutorials about it for some more information on how.

Comment: do not use `if button pressed, then run motor` and `if timer, then run motor` ........... instead use `if button pressed, then set flag` and `if timer, then set flag` and `if flag set, then run motor`

Comment: I'm also confused because your two functions both do the same thing.  What do you actually want to see happening?  If you want the stepper to just constantly step then remove the 30 second delay.